# is it possible to install postgresql-dev in bullseye

Tags: postgresql, rust

Now I am using `rust:1.54-bullseye` as my base image, when I run my app it shows error:`./reddwarf_music: error while loading shared libraries: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`, I searching from internet and someone told that install `postgresql-devel` would fix this problem .now I tried to install `postgresql-devel` in the base image using this command:

```
RUN apt install postgresql-devel
```

but it tell me:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-devel
The command '/bin/sh -c apt install postgresql-devel' returned a non-zero code: 100
exit status 100
Error: exit status 100
```

what should I do to install this package in `rust:1.54-bullseye`? I have already tried this way:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install postgresql-devel
```

install `postgresql-devel` failed, could not find the package.

Comment: Are you sure the package is really named `postgresql-devel`? For me it's `libpq-dev`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried this command to install the `libpq.so.5` dependencies:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install postgresql -y
```

works. It will install dependencies but the postgresql still too large, the better way is install libpq5 like this:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libpq5 -y
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have already modified my question and answer to make it more clear.@Community

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best is to use docker-compose with a better segreation of responsibility.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    image: rust:1.54-bullseye
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DB_HOSTNAME=db
      - DB_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}

    volumes:
      - bullseye-data:/var/lib/bullseye/db
    networks:
      - bullseye

  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      - POSTGRES_DB=bullseye
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - bullseye-database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - bullseye

volumes:
  bullseye-database:
  bullseye-data:

networks:
  bullseye:
```